# How to call json.load inside a class' method while importing the json module at the top

Tags: python, json, load, self

I can't understand why json.load retrieves me a "TypeError: load() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" when calling the loading method if i import the load method from json at the beginning. Instead importing it inside the method and calling game_data = load(file) functions. Why? How can i get it done importing load at the top like all the other methods?

```
class start:
    from module_x import method_y
    from json import load

    def __init__(self,game,data = {}):
        self.name = game + '.json'
        self.data = data

def xyz():
        self.method_y() #calling other methods with self.method is okay

def loading(self , file = None): 
        if not file:
            file = self.name
        with open(file, 'r') as file:
            game_data = self.load(file) #here is not okay
        return game_data
```

instead is okay:

```
 def loading(self , file = None): 
        from json import load
        if not file:
            file = self.name
        with open(file, 'r') as file:
            game_data = load(file) 
        return game_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the function"load" of the module "json" only takes one argument, but since it is now a method of your created class it will always get "self" as the first argument and the passed argument as the second one.
So it is not possible to directly import the function into the class. You need to import the module itself or import the function inside your loading function or the last option to import it at the top of your file only then you can call and use it as intended.

Option 1:

```py
class myClass:
    import json
    def myLoadindFunction(self, fileObject):
        fileContent = self.json.load(fileObject)
```

Option 2:

```py
class myClass:
    def myLoadindFunction(self, fileObject):
        from json import load
        fileContent = load(fileObject)
```

Option 3:

```py
from json import load
class myClass:
    def myLoadindFunction(self, fileObject):
        fileContent = load(fileObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply proper indents, the issue is that your instance is passed to the method called. When you write `self.method()`, Python will call `method(self)`.

You can import the module json instead of the method, then you'll have `self.module.method()`.

```
class start:
    import json

    def __init__(self,game,data = {}):
        self.name = game + '.json'
        self.data = data

    def loading(self , file = None): 
            if not file:
                file = self.name
            with open(file, 'r') as file:
                game_data = self.json.load(file)
            return game_data
```

As a side-note: you should avoid putting imports anywhere but at the beginning of the file. From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide:

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
>   comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.